# What produces Error 10001 in vb6 at connection string?

Tags: vb6, oledb, jet

After the last Windows/Office update Feb 2020 on some of the computers the following connection string in vb6 produces an

> "Catastrophic Failure : (10001)"

```
ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;DataSource="+cMDBFile
```

After installing MicrosoftDatabaseEngine2010 (32bit) the error was gone, but only until the next Windows Restart/Windows Update.

After changing to

```
ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;DataSource="+cMDBFile
```

it seems to run.

My MDBFile Format is ACCESS2003

The connection is created as follows:

```
Dim objConn as ADODB.Connection 
Set objConn = new ADODB.Connection 

With objConn 
    .ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;DataSource="+cMDBFile 
    .Open 
End With
```

The Error Occurs at `.Open`.

Does anybody know what happened?
The last years no error occurred (except 3420 in December of course).
Is this an error produced by Microsoft, if so, how can I tell them?

Comment: What is the command / code that uses the connecting string? How is it attempting to open the DB?

Comment: Dim objConn as ADODB.Connection
Set objConn = new ADODB.Connection
With objConn
   .ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;DataSource="+cMDBFile
   .Open
End With
The Error Occurs at .Open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You connection string should according to your database type.

more likely when you are connection to mdb file, you should use

```
PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=
```